# How to process CIDR block/Text processing?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ip, cidr

I've to process CIDR block and add 2 to the last octet in single line to use it inside of a shell script. 
For example, if my CIDR block is 10.0.0.0/8, then my output should be 10.0.0.2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your line only contains the IP address and block, such as:

```
BLOCK=10.0.0.0/8
```

You can use `awk`:

```
cut -d/ -f1 <<< "$BLOCK" | awk -F . 'BEGIN {OFS="."} {print $1,$2,$3,$4+2}'
```

Comment: Alternatively with bash: `IFS=./ read a b c d e <<< 10.0.0.0/8; echo $a.$b.$c.$((d+2))`

Comment: or `awk -F '[./]' 'BEGIN {OFS="."} {print $1,$2,$3,$4+2}' <<< $BLOCK`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# convert IP to decimal
ip2dec() {
  set -- ${1//./ }     # split $1 with "." to $1 $2 $3 $4
  declare -i dec       # set integer attribute
  dec=$1*256*256*256+$2*256*256+$3*256+$4
  echo $dec
}

# convert decimal to IP
dec2ip() {
  declare -i ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4
  ip1=$1/256/256/256
  ip2=($1-$ip1*256*256*256)/256/256
  ip3=($1-$ip1*256*256*256-$ip2*256*256)/256
  ip4=$1-$ip1*256*256*256-$ip2*256*256-$ip3*256
  echo $ip1.$ip2.$ip3.$ip4
}

dec=$(ip2dec ${1%/*}) # remove slash and mask
dec=$((dec+2))        # increment
dec2ip $dec
```

Example: `./script.sh 10.0.0.0/8`

Output:

```
10.0.0.2
```

This script was derived from my [IP range generator script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681431/3776858).

Comment: it's working good, but i'm looking for a simple one liner like above one. 

Thanks