# How to convert string into integer in shell scrip?

Tags: bash, shell

In a Bash script, I would like to split a IP by dot delimiter.
But When I am passing a variable in For Loop it is behaving like string.

```
StartIP=10.10.140.10
EndIP=10.10.140.15

StartIP_Prefix_1=`echo $StartIP | awk -F"\." '{print $1}'`
StartIP_Prefix_2=`echo $StartIP | awk -F"\." '{print $2}'`
StartIP_Prefix_3=`echo $StartIP | awk -F"\." '{print $3}'`
StartIP_Prefix_4=`echo $StartIP | awk -F"\." '{print $4}'`

EndIP_Prefix_3=`echo $EndIP | awk -F"\." '{print $3}'`
EndIP_Prefix_4=`echo $EndIP | awk -F"\." '{print $4}'`

IP_Prefix=$StartIP_Prefix_1.$StartIP_Prefix_2


IP_Range=$IP_Prefix.{$StartIP_Prefix_3..$EndIP_Prefix_3}.
{$StartIP_Prefix_4..$EndIP_Prefix_4}

for ip in $IP_Range
do
  echo $ip

done
```

After running the script, It is showing 10.10.{40..40}.{10..15}

expect : I want it show all the IPs like:
    10.10.140.10
    10.10.140.11
    10.10.140.12
    10.10.140.13
    10.10.140.14
    10.10.140.15

Please, Let me know if there any other option to find out IPs between two IPs.

Comment: Not clear, please provide sample Input with expected sample output here in CODE TAGS.

Comment: This might help: [IP range generator script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35681157/3776858)

Comment: Tangentially see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: All regular variables in Bash are strings. Some can be interpreted as numbers in some contexts, but you are fundamentally dealing with strings all the time.